# Set a custom date within select option

Tags: angularjs, datetimepicker, angular-material

**What I want to achieve:**
Within Select, I would like to be able to select the start date and end date and when i click the 'Apply' button, I would like to record the values of startDate and endDate to calculate # of months selected. This value needs to be passed to the ng-model 'monthLimit'

**script.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['angularjs-datetime-picker', 'ngMaterial']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.monthLimit = 'Test';
  $scope.startDate = '2016-03-02';
  $scope.endDate = '2016-03-10';
 $scope.monthLimitChanged = function(){
   if ($scope.monthLimit == 'Custom'){
     console.log('start date', $scope.startDate);
     console.log('end date', $scope.endDate);
   }
   $scope.showReport(); // calls a method that triggers a
   // http request and pass in the required params
 } 
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.2/angular-material.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/kineticsocial/angularjs-datetime-picker/master/angularjs-datetime-picker.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.7/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/kineticsocial/angularjs-datetime-picker/master/angularjs-datetime-picker.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <md-select
        ng-model="monthLimit"
        ng-change="monthLimitChanged()">
        <md-option value="Test">Test</md-option>
        <md-option value="Custom">
            Custom
            <div style="display:inline-block;">
                <input style="width:90px;" datetime-picker date-format="yyyy-MM-dd" date-only required ng-model="startDate" /> -  
            </div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;">
                <input style="width:90px;" datetime-picker date-format="yyyy-MM-dd" date-only required ng-model="endDate" />
            </div>
            <button ng-click="monthLimitChanged()" style="display:inline-block;">Apply</button>
        </md-option>
      </md-select>
  </body>

</html>
```

**style.css**

```
md-select{
    padding: 30px;
    width: 250px;
}

md-option:hover{
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

**Plunker**
http://plnkr.co/edit/z4j3PKkEuKh4rd6u3dDG?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment.js (http://momentjs.com/) if you don't mind using another JS library and just do something like:

```
(moment.duration(moment($scope.endDate).diff(moment($scope.startDate)))).asMonths()
```

Comment: That would give me the total # of months selected. My problem is that I am unable to select dates within the select.